# How to get text of anchor tag for google analytics in AMP page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

Currently am implementing Google analytics in my webapp. I have few pages which are part of AMP. In our valid amp pages we have implemented google analytics.

As per our GA tracking when user click on any anchor tag we need to pass text of anchor tag. since Amp not allowing any custom script am unable to push to data layer of GA
here is my current code

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"
},
 "triggers": {
  "trackClickOnHeader" : {
  "on": "click",
  "selector": "#header",
  "request": "event",
  "vars": {
    "eventCategory": "ui-components",
    "eventAction": "header-click"
  }
 }
 }
}
```

please some one help to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its not the best solution as you must add each anchor id separately, but this should work:

```
"triggers": {
                "trackAnchorClicks": {
                    "on": "click",
                    "selector": "#anchor-id-1",
                    "request": "event",
                    "vars": {
                        "eventId": "clickOnSpecialAnchor-1"

                    }
                },
                "trackAnchorClicks": {
                    "on": "click",
                    "selector": "#anchor-id-2",
                    "request": "event",
                    "vars": {
                        "eventId": "clickOnSpecialAnchor-2"
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tested it  here:

https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-analytics%2Fsource%2F

view-source:https://amp-publisher-samples-staging.herokuapp.com/amp-analytics/embed?user=r4aw5foq&account=ampbyexample

so maybe some handwork on the google side is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `data-vars-event-label` tag to each of your anchor links, you can access that label via the `${eventLabel}`

So if you have

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/1" data-vars-event-label="example-1">
<a href="https://www.example.com/2" data-vars-event-label="example-2">
```

you can add just one trigger as follows:

```
triggers": {
  "trackAnchorClicks":
    "on": "click",
    "selector": "a"
    "request": "event"
}
```

and your event label will be added to the query params as `eventLabel`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **data-vars-event-label** attribute to your anchor links.

```
<a href="{{your-link}}" data-vars-event-label="{{var-to-access}}">
```

You can access this value via ${eventLabel} in your analytics file like this.

```
"name-of-your-choice": "${eventLabel}"
```

Thats it!